# How to change windowBackground of dialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I want to change the windowBackground of dialogFragment.
It changed windowBackground at API 32 But why does it not change? at API 34
What has changed at between API 32 and API 34?

I just have simple dialog .. for test of background color
I'd like to change to grey.

at API 32
[API32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1QkY.png)

at API 34
[API34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBjEl.png)